# ui-router reinitializing angular controllers on state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there an easy way using ui-router to force all my controllers to only be initialized once? Like a singleton. As of right now, every time I change to a state, the controller linked to that state is reinitialized. I don't want this to happen. This seems like it should be simple, but I could not find a solution to this anywhere online.

Comment: Put your init logic into service

Comment: My logic is in a service, but I call methods on those services in my controller which make requests for data. I only want those requests made once, not every time I switch to that state.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. How can controller not get called if other things changed, say scope variables? basically, I am suggesting abstracting all your code in controller into a service. Update: since you only want service gets called once, it is different story. In this case, cache your expensive service call result.

Comment: I was hoping ui-router had some way to support this. It seems like a common issue. I doubt everyone that use ui-router for navbars wants the controllers for each view to be reinitialized every time a user navigates to a menu in that nav?

Comment: Just imaging if you switch states and some rootscope variables updated, and you switch back to old state which depends on rootscope variable. How can you handle this?

Comment: I designed all of my controllers to be self contained. They do not rely on any rootscope variables, so I don't have to worry about their state being changed from another view. If ui-router doesn't support this, can you think of a workaround in angular to achieve a singleton controller?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid calling controller since DOM is updated when switching states, ie template gets called which depends on controller. As a singleton controller, I don't know any answer to that other than caching service results.

Comment: Ok well thanks for at least exploring the problem with me. I might have to actually change up my architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to handle things like one-time or global operations is to have an application level controller on an element that wraps all your ui-views:

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>...</head>
    <body ng-controller="ApplicationController">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

ApplicationController can then reponsible for one-time operations. It gets initialised once (when the app starts) and will persist between route and state changes.

The controllers associated with your states should only be concerned with constructing their own views, not performing one-time operations. If the state controllers need to access shared data, then that data should be stored in a service as suggested by ABOS. State controllers should request that shared data from the service, and the service should be the one deciding if it should return cached data, or make a fresh service call.